# how to Calculate 3D Object movements in c?

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

I am new to 3D programming,
Creating 3D objects from Blender and pass into my Project in iOS.

Now I am able to render object on my screen. Even I am able to apply gesture like pinch to zoom in/out.

Now I want to implement as I swipe left from one position toward left Object should rotate with its y axis.
I have implement Slop Formulate As:

```
float angle =atan2f((y2 - y1),(x2 - x1));
```

but it gives more difference in angle. Shortly The 3D object is not moving the actual direction.
And the angle should be rotate in small value.(below 45 degrees) with respect to x,y and z axis.

I want to rotate it back to align it with the x-y plane, but the problem is I don't know the angles, so I need to calculate/estimate them somehow

1. how to calculate the angles?
2. how to rotate it when I know the angles?

Comment: Ohhk.. Do you know how to implement it? @Ankur

Comment: I dont have much idea on 3D programming and OpenGLES, I am also struggling with this, I found [iSGL3D Example](http://isgl3d.com/download) which has some good examples with all of those calculation you want. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks Ankur, The Skinning Test is example from isGL3D is same thing which I am want. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Can u share some more code including actions you have assigned ?

Comment: @KaranAlangat  1.Render camera on screen. 2.After detecting texture, placed my object. 3.Apply Zoom In/Out on it. Just Thats it. I have done. Not done any coding on rotation of object.

Comment: Didn't you check the cocos3d sample projects ? New project it self contains action to rotate

Comment: May I know whr is that code?(file) Coz when I go through the cocos3d project there are several files. I have checked few code. But didn't get anything. @Karan Alangat

Comment: i believe u got the code for actions . .. .

Comment: Yes, I have got that cocos3D code. But My project is not implementing POD files, It uses .ac 3d object files, So does the .ac files supports cocoa3d objects? OR can I grab the modes, meshes from .ac files to Coco3d objects? @Karan Alangat

Comment: Cocos3d supports only pod files. You can create pod files from blender , 3dmax,maya files . Refer this link > http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-importing-converting-collada-to-pod/

Answer (score 1):

Just check the cocos3d sample projects .New project it self contains action to rotate.
Or create a new project as sample by yourself.

1. Create a New Project.
2. Open the Classes folder in navigator pane on
   the left side.
3. Then Select Classes Folder.
4. Select the scene.m file.

   There you can see in initializeScene(). It contains the code to create a new cc3meshnode and actions to rotate it.